# How do you link 2 web parts on a SharePoint Page?

Tags: sharepoint

I want to build a SharePoint page template for a item like "a Company".  I'd like to have a Wiki part on the top of the page and a List of documents on the bottom.  Let's use Pepsi as my example.  I want the top Wiki part to be info about Pepsi, but I want the Document list to be filtered to **ONLY** show Pepsi items in the list.  How do you accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, I think this is possible using the out-of-the-box filter web parts in MOSS 2007. Ton Stegeman (a SharePoint MVP) has a post that sounds similar to what you're trying to achieve (using MOSS 2007):

- [SharePoint 2007 Filter webparts - using the Page Field Filter webpart on a Lookup field](http://www.tonstegeman.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=29)

As Scott Price points out you can also write your own. Ton's blog also has some guidance there too:

- [MOSS 2007 Filter webparts part 1 - create your own provider and consumer](http://www.tonstegeman.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=37)

Answer (score 0):

Many of the built in web parts within SharePoint are connectable.  However, to achieve what you want, you will likely have to build your own.  Take a look at the following article for an overview of what is required.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms469765.aspx